# Create a string with a variable definition in Python (of a nympy.arange object)

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm working on a Python script, and I would like to generate a string with the definition of a variable, which is a numpy array. I want this to write it to an external file or to screen instead of printing/writing the whole array.

To make it clear, I have:

```
import numpy as np
normalization = np.arange(4, 11, 0.1)
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
normalization_string = 'np.arange(4, 11, 0.1)'
```

without having to write it manually, but specifying of course to generate the string from the variable `normalization`.

Is there a simple way to generate that string?

Comment: Simply answer: No and don't try to do it. Whatever problem you try to solve with this: There's probably a much better and simpler way.

Comment: The problem is that I define some variables in my script in a different way (like different numbers for that `np.arange`) every time I run it, and I want the script to save these variables in an external file, but in a human readable way (in order to compare different output files at the end). What would you suggest?

Comment: Define you "start"-parameters: i.e. `start, stop, step = 4, 11, 0.1`, then create the array: `np.arange(start, stop, step)` and then just safe `start`, `stop` and `step` and whatever output you have.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't realize it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can't because a variable simply doesn't know (because the variable doesn't care) how it was created.

For example in your case `np.arange` is just a function. It returns an `np.ndarray`, however there are several ways to create a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(4, 5, 0.1)
array([ 4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,  4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9])

>>> np.arange(40, 50) / 10.
array([ 4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,  4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9])

>>> np.array(range(40, 50, 1)) / 10.
array([ 4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,  4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9])

>>> np.linspace(4, 4.9, 10)
array([ 4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,  4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9])
```

All of them create the same array.

---

My advise:

Just safe your parameters that change between runs, for example if you want to modify the "step":

```
step = 0.1

arr = np.arange(4, 11, step)
# do something with arr

res = ... # the result

# safe only the "step" and "res".
print('np.arange(4, 11, {})'.format(step))  # creating a string
```

If start, stop and step vary:

```
start = 4
stop = 11
step = 0.1

arr = np.arange(start, stop, step)
# do something with arr

res = ... # the result

# safe "start", "stop", "step" and "res".
print('np.arange({}, {}, {})'.format(start, stop, step))  # or create the string
```

I added the `print`s mostly because you explicitly asked for the string representation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround:

Use a specific class which delegates all variable definitions, as such:

```
class VariableConstructor():

    def __init__(self):
        self.idsTable = []

    def construct_primitive(self, value):   
        x = value
        self.idsTable.append( (id(x), type(value), str(value)) )

        return x

    def construct_object(self, constructor, args=None, kwargs=None):
        if args is not  None and kwargs is not None:
            x = constructor(*args, **kwargs)
            self.idsTable.append( (id(x), constructor, str(args) + ',' + str(kwargs)) )
        elif args is not None:
            x = constructor(*args)
            self.idsTable.append( (id(x), constructor, str(args)) )
        elif kwargs is not None:
            self.idsTable.append( (id(x), constructor, str(kwargs)) )
            x = constructor(**kwargs)
        else:
            x = constructor()
            self.idsTable.append( (id(x), constructor, '') )

        return x

    def get_string_representation(self, variable):
        _, t, args = filter(lambda x: x[0] == id(variable), self.idsTable)[0]
        return str(t).replace('<','').replace('>','')+':'+args
```

then, this is some example code:

```
import numpy as np

vc = VariableConstructor()

i = vc.construct_primitive(5)
f = vc.construct_primitive(10.)
l = vc.construct_object(list)
arr = vc.construct_object(np.arange, (4,11,0.1))



print(vc.get_string_representation(i))
print(vc.get_string_representation(f))
print(vc.get_string_representation(l))
print(vc.get_string_representation(arr))
```

which will output:

```
type 'int':5
type 'float':10.0
type 'list':
built-in function arange:(4, 11, 0.1)
```

Some notes:
 - This is a sample code, bugs may be lurking anywhere.
 - You can easily change how the strings of your variables will be inside `get_string_representation()` method.
 - Your code may be difficult to read from someone else.

**EDIT: I misread what you said and thought that you wanted a general way for any variable. Did not see that it was just for `np.arange` objects. This is an overkill.** (The appropriate answer was in comments)

*However, I think I will leave my answer here since it answers the title of the question.*